# Pygame sin,cos,tan caculating circular movement path

Tags: pygame

I have been struggling for few days know trying to figure out how to make for example a image move in circular path. I have looked other posts here but i just can't get it.

So how do i move image in circular path. My code only moves my image 45 degrees and stops then. I would need it to go full circle and continue doing it.

Current Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

CENTER = (200, 200)
RADIUS = 100
x = 0
y = 0

satelliteCenter = (CENTER[0]+RADIUS, CENTER[1])

run = 1
while run == 1:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = 0
      pygame.quit()

  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  vector = x-CENTER[0], y-CENTER[1]
  x +=1

  distance = (vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2)**0.5

  if distance > 0:
    scalar = RADIUS / distance
    satelliteCenter = (
      int(round( CENTER[0] + vector[0]*scalar )),
      int(round( CENTER[1] + vector[1]*scalar )) )

  screen.fill((255,255,255))
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (71,153,192), CENTER, RADIUS)
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (243,79,79), satelliteCenter, 16)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `pygame.math.Vector2` and rotate it each frame, scale it by the radius and add it to the `CENTER` position to get the current center of the small circle.

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

CENTER = (200, 200)
RADIUS = 100
# A unit vector pointing to the right.
direction = pygame.math.Vector2(1, 0)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    direction.rotate_ip(4)  # By 4 degrees.
    # Normalize it, so that the length doesn't change because
    # of floating point inaccuracies.
    direction.normalize_ip()
    # Scale direction vector, add it to CENTER and convert to ints.
    ball_pos = [int(i) for i in CENTER+direction*RADIUS]

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (71,153,192), CENTER, RADIUS)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (243,79,79), ball_pos, 16)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

---

Edit: If you want the red ball to follow the mouse, then your example actually works if you set x and y to the mouse pos `x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

CENTER = (200, 200)
RADIUS = 100
x = 0
y = 0

satelliteCenter = (CENTER[0]+RADIUS, CENTER[1])

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    vector = x-CENTER[0], y-CENTER[1]

    distance = (vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2)**0.5

    if distance > 0:
        scalar = RADIUS / distance
        satelliteCenter = (
            int(round( CENTER[0] + vector[0]*scalar )),
            int(round( CENTER[1] + vector[1]*scalar ))
        )

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (71,153,192), CENTER, RADIUS)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (243,79,79), satelliteCenter, 16)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with vectors, there are some good videos on [khanacademy.org](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces).

Comment: On your original answer. Is it possible to change the speed?

Comment: Sure, I just chose 4 degrees (`direction.rotate_ip(4)`) per frame arbitrarily.